# How to show a progress indicator animation overlayed on current screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, loading, progress, indicator

How can I show an overlayed loading indicator above the current screen in flutter?
Like when the user tries to log in and while making the http request I want a spinning indicator to show above the current screen content without dimming or anything so I don't wan't to use a Dialog.

Something like this from Pinterest app for example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make a common loader widget

```
class LoaderTransparent extends StatelessWidget {
double height;
double width;
Color colorValue;
LoaderTransparent({this.colorValue});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Container(
    height: height,
    width: width,
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
            height: 60.0,
            width: 60.0,
            child:
                //Image.asset('assets/images/loader.gif',fit: BoxFit.fill,) // use you custom loader or default loader
          CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
          Colors.blue),
          strokeWidth: 5.0))));
      }
  }
```

In your screen use like this

```
Scaffold(
    body:
    Stack(children: [
    Container(
      width: width,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[ // user screen ui
        
          ],)
      ),
   true ? LoaderTransparent() : Container()    // true or false conditions  according loader show or hide
])
 );
```

Comment: I have another question, is there a way where I can do this when the user logout from a drawer? I mean how can I use a stack if I don't know at which screen will the user be when the logout button is tapped in the drawer? so any ideas?

Comment: You can use stack on your app home screen where you are using drawer.

Comment: yeah that would work but I'm using the drawer on several screens for the user to be able to access it from almost anywhere.

Comment: If you are using redux your loader state will be same for all screen you need stack for each screen because  we can not check where is user  then if logout by user current screen loader will be see.

Comment: yeah seems like there isn't a better way than using the stack on each screen. Thank you again

Comment: You can use the stack as the root of all widgets or screens.Then no need on the stack on each screen

Comment: Do you mean by using a stack as wrapper on MaterialApp or what exactly, I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with the use of showDialog.

```
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isAndroid
        ? Center(child: SizedBox(height: 40, width: 40, child: Center(child: ProgressIndicatorLight())))
        : Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
                SizedBox(height: 6),
                Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Text(
                    'LOADING',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: kLoadingFontSize),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
  },
);
```